# How curdate() works in comparisons in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to retrieve entries in my DB using curdate() and I think there is some underlying logic that I'm unaware of. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE event='bar' 
AND created_at >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 90) 
AND created_at <= CURDATE()
```

This call returns with the previous 90 days but it does not have any of the entries from today. As I understand it curdate() is only YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD and completely ignores the time of day, we save that for curtime() and now(). I suspect that time is being included somewhere in here because when I make a similar call in Rails and pass the date as a DateTime.beginning_of_day it works whereas any other way it will not include today up to a certain hour.

I've checked out a few sources, including the MySQL reference manual, and haven't come up with any real answers. Is it possible that some element of the current time is being included in the query or is there some other business going on behind closed doors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `created_at` column is a full `datetime` type, then when comparing to a date, it will take the beginning of that date.

So, comparing to `2011-01-01` is akin to comparing to `2011-01-01 00:00:00`.  That's why you're not getting anything back for `CURDATE()` (unless the `created_at` timestamp is **exactly** midnight on that date).

Example:

```
select curdate();
-- 2011-01-31

select cast(curdate() as datetime);
-- 2011-01-31 00:00:00

select if('2011-01-31' <= curdate(), 'yep', 'not this time');
-- yep

select if('2011-01-31 00:00:01' <= curdate(), 'yep', 'not this time');
-- not this time

select if('2011-01-31 01:00:00' <= adddate(curdate(), interval 1 day), 'yep', 'not this time');
-- yep
```

Comment: +1: When in doubt, check the data types of the columns -- MySQL has DATE, and DATETIME.

Comment: Apparently that column is a TIMESTAMP and from what I'm reading it seems more like I should just change the column to a DATETIME before I try to cater to TIMESTAMP. Would you say that's accurate?

Comment: @keybored.  Exactly -- and you're comparing it to a `DATE`.  When comparing a `DATE` to a `TIMESTAMP`, the `DATE` is going to be assumed as midnight at the beginning of that day (i.e. 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds).  You should either be comparing `TIMESTAMP`s to `TIMESTAMP`s or using something like `adddate` to get any records during that `DATE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm up and running now.